# sort fields within a line

Tags: sorting, unix

input:

```
87    6,1,9,13
3     9,4,14,35,38,13
31    3,1,6,5
```

(i.e. a tab-delimited column where the second field is a comma-delimited list of unordered integers.)

desired output:

```
87    1,6,9,13
3     4,9,13,14,35,38
31    1,3,5,6
```

Goal:
for each line *separately*,  sort the comma-separated list appearing in the second field.  i.e. sort the 2nd column **within** for each line separately.

Note: the rows should *not* be re-ordered.

What I've tried:

`sort` - Since the order of the rows should not change, then `sort` is simply not applicable.

`awk`  - since the greater file is tab-delimited, not comma-delimited, it cannot parse the second column as multiple "sub-fields"

There might be a perl way?  I know nothing about perl though...

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by simple perl oneliner:

```sh
perl -F'/\t/' -alne'$s=join",",sort{$a<=>$b}split",",$F[1];print"$F[0]\t$s"'
```

and shell (`bash`) one as well:

```sh
while read a b;do echo -e "$a\t$(echo $b|tr , '\n'|sort -n|tr '\n' ,|sed 's/,$//')"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while read LINE; do 
   echo -e "$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}')\t$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}' | tr ',' '\n' | sort -n | paste -s -d,)"; 
done < input
```

Obviously a lot going on here so here we go:

- `input` contains your input
- `$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}')` prints the first field, pretty straightforward
- `$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}' | tr ',' '\n' | sort -n | paste -s -d,)` prints the second field, but breaks it down into lines by replacing the commas by newlines (`tr ',' '\n'`), then sort numerically, then assemble the lines back to comma-delimited values (`paste -s -d,`).

---

```
$ cat input
87    6,1,9,13
3     9,4,14,35,38,13
31    3,1,6,5

$ while read LINE; do echo -e "$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}')\t$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}' | tr ',' '\n' | sort -n | paste -s -d,)"; done < input
87      1,6,9,13
3       4,9,13,14,35,38
31      1,3,5,6
```

Comment: But ` awk '{print $2}' | tr ',' '\n' `  will result in just one big column, e.g. from my example:  "1\n6\n9\n13\n9\n4\n13 ..." - so then you lose track of which fields belonged to which row

Comment: It shouldn't. Each line is processed individually. The list is broken down to multiple lines so it can be sorted, but then the `paste` command will put it back as one. Are you getting a different output?

Comment: `awk '{print $2} | tr ',' '\n'' prints the second column and pipes it into the `tr` utility.  But I though that the `awk` command would "complete" first (i.e. print the second column for every entry), then pipe that entire result into `tr` as one input.  Then `tr` would operate on the entire input at once - resulting in one conglomerate, single-columned list - hence losing the original entries.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: The `awk` in this case only works on the single line. It's arguably overkill seeing as `awk` typically works on multiple lines: `cat input | awk '{print $2}'` (I know this is an unnecessary `cat`, just proving a point) will print the 2nd column of the whole file because you're passing the whole output of `cat` to `awk`. The same applies if you just use `echo` of a single line; you're passing some input to the command.

Comment: oh yes, now i see - hence the `while read` loop.  i understand now.  thnak you

Answer (score 0):

Another way:
`echo happybirthday|awk '{split($0,A);asort(A); for (i=1;i<length(A);i++) {print A[i]}}' FS=""|tr -d '\n';echo aabdhhipprty`

I didn't know how to get back to this page after recovering login info, so am posting as a guest.